# HANA XSJS app authentication method: what to choose?

Tags: hana, xsjs

We are developing SAAS web application on SAP HANA XS Engine.

We have subscription based product packages and we want to manage user authentication on web. So, we removed XS Engine authentication.

Now we have login page that use XSJS methods for authentication. It is working for login page and it redirect to another page. However, I don't know how can I control session in the redirected page. How it is working in XS Engine.

Could you provide some information about this?

According to this [documentation](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/31/111b1b9f2b4c3ebad38f0cc50d3e91/content.htm) it seems SPNego or SAML is suitable for us. But, I read another document that says SAML is no longer available after SP 8.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HANA Cloud, you can activate the SAML or LDAP login, and works with SSO, btw you need to develop some code to integrate this

OR

On login page, you can create a TOKEN, and authenticate every request based on this TOKEN, this solution is good to SP9 or SP8

OR

You can use $.session to manage sessions, available on SP10 and later

Comment: Thank you. Especially for the third one.